# How to select rows between duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with orders of a taxi for day. I need to know how much km were lost on a circles. So I cant figure out how to select rows between duplicates.
For this dataframe:

| index | driver | from | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Tom | Manhattan | 35 |
| 1 | Tom | Brooklyn | 40 |
| 2 | Tom | Queens | 25 |
| 3 | Nick | Manhattan | 35 |
| 4 | Nick | Brooklyn | 35 |
| 5 | Nick | Manhattan | 75 |
| 6 | Nick | Queens | 25 |
| 7 | Krish | Queens | 40 |
| 8 | Krish | Brooklyn | 35 |
| 9 | Krish | Manhattan | 75 |
| 10 | Krish | Queens | 25 |
| 11 | Jack | Queens | 25 |
| 12 | Jack | Brooklyn | 40 |
| 13 | Jack | Manhattan | 35 |

Result will be:

| index | driver | from | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Nick | Manhattan | 35 |
| 4 | Nick | Brooklyn | 35 |
| 7 | Krish | Queens | 40 |
| 8 | Krish | Brooklyn | 35 |
| 9 | Krish | Manhattan | 75 |

```
data = {'driver': ['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 
                   'Krish', 'Krish', 'Krish', 'Krish', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack'], 
        'from': ['Manhattan', 'Brooklyn', 'Queens', 'Manhattan', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Queens',
                 'Queens', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Queens', 'Queens', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan'],
        'distance': [35, 40, 25, 35, 35, 75, 25, 
                    40, 35, 75, 25, 25, 40, 35]}
```

I can select duplicated rows by using `df.duplicated(['driver', 'from'], keep=False)` but it selects only duplicated rows not in between them.

Comment: is Queens -> Brooklyn -> Manhattan -> Queens not a circle?

Comment: @EpicCoder if you're thinking about "Krish", yes this is a circle, but it looks like OP wants to exclude the last step

Comment: Yes, i want to exclude last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) values and extend them in forward and backward (with a [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to exclude the last step of the loop), per driver, using [`groupby.cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html), and finally keeping only the overlapping rows (with a boolean AND: `&`):

```
dup = df.duplicated(subset=['driver', 'from'], keep=False)

m1 = dup.groupby(df['driver']).cummax()
m2 = dup[::-1].groupby(df['driver']).transform(lambda x: x.cummax().shift())

out = df[m1 & m2]
```

Output:

```
      driver       from  distance
index                            
3       Nick  Manhattan        35
4       Nick   Brooklyn        35
7      Krish     Queens        40
8      Krish   Brooklyn        35
9      Krish  Manhattan        75
```

Intermediates:

```
      driver       from  distance     up     m1     m2  m1&m2
index                                                        
0        Tom  Manhattan        35  False  False  False  False
1        Tom   Brooklyn        40  False  False  False  False
2        Tom     Queens        25  False  False    NaN  False
3       Nick  Manhattan        35   True   True   True   True
4       Nick   Brooklyn        35  False   True   True   True
5       Nick  Manhattan        75   True   True  False  False
6       Nick     Queens        25  False   True    NaN  False
7      Krish     Queens        40   True   True   True   True
8      Krish   Brooklyn        35  False   True   True   True
9      Krish  Manhattan        75  False   True   True   True
10     Krish     Queens        25   True   True    NaN  False
11      Jack     Queens        25  False  False  False  False
12      Jack   Brooklyn        40  False  False  False  False
13      Jack  Manhattan        35  False  False    NaN  False
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this idea, but my output doesn't match with yours.Please check:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'driver': ['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 'Nick', 
                   'Krish', 'Krish', 'Krish', 'Krish', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack'], 
        'from': ['Manhattan', 'Brooklyn', 'Queens', 'Manhattan', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Queens',
                 'Queens', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Queens', 'Queens', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan'],
        'distance': [35, 40, 25, 35, 35, 75, 25, 
                    40, 35, 75, 25, 25, 40, 35]})

data['first'] = np.where(data.duplicated(['driver', 'from'], keep=False)==True,1,0)

print(data[(data.iloc[::-1]['first'].cumsum() >= 1) &
     (data['first'].cumsum() >= 1)].drop_duplicates(subset=['driver', 'from']).drop(columns=['first']))



     driver   from     distance
3   Nick    Manhattan   35
4   Nick    Brooklyn    35
6   Nick    Queens      25
7   Krish   Queens      40
8   Krish   Brooklyn    35
9   Krish   Manhattan   75
```